# 301 permanent redirection of inner pages using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Please help with the www and non-www redirection. I don't mean the homepage.

I want to redirect the non-www of any inner page to its www version 
for example

redirect http://dummy.com/contacts to http://www.balgev.com/contacts

now when i go to http://dummy.com/contacts it redirects me to http://www.dummy.com

Please help me:)

Comment: This has been answered about 5639576394 times alone here on SO. You probably looked at those answers. Since you ask again we assume that something in those answers did not work for you. Would you mind telling us what did not work for you? What your specific problem is? Why the examples do not help you?

Comment: Can you show your current .htaccess rule?